# ESLint for storybook files

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint, storybook

How do I can write script for the stories extensions also?
Currently I have:

`"eslint": "eslint '**/{*,*.stories}.{ts,tsx}'",`

My structure:

```
src
  components
    SomeComponent
      SomeComponent.tsx
      SomeComponent.stories.tsx
      index.ts
      types.ts
```

but script as I wrote, works well only for tsx and ts files, but I would like to check `.stories.tsx` also

Answer (score 0):

Just doing this should be enough to include the story files.

```
"eslint": "eslint **/*.{ts,tsx}",
```

Another way of doing it is to use the `—ext` flag.

```
"eslint": "eslint -ext .ts,.tsx **",
```

Comment: It didn't help, maybe I need to add settings somewhere else?

Comment: What happens if you just do `eslint src/**`?

Comment: the same( checks all files but not the .stories.tsx files

Comment: Do you have a `.eslintignore` file somewhere?

Comment: I don't have `. eslintignore`

Comment: I suggest you make another simple test project somewhere, this is most likely hidden config somewhere.